# SSH.NET Connection always disconnects after RunCommand

Tags: c#, ssh, cisco, ssh.net

I'm trying to connect to our cisco switch via SSH.NET and run multiple commands on it (up to 200) and read the results. After one command, the connection always disconnects.

Code:

```
public void ConnectSSH(string username, string password)
{
    sshclient = new SshClient(_name, username, password);
    sshclient.Connect();
}

public string ExecuteSSH(string command)
{
    //if (!sshclient.IsConnected)
    //    sshclient.Connect();
    SshCommand x = sshclient.CreateCommand(command);
    x.Execute();
    return x.Result;
}

public void DisconnectSSH()
{
    sshclient.Disconnect();
    sshclient.Dispose();
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
ConnectSSH("user", "pw")
foreach (string exCmd in listToExecute)
    {
        listReturn.Add(ExecuteSSH(exCmd));
    }
DisconnectSSH();
```

Disconnect happens everytime right after x.Execute(). No Error in x.Error, x.ExitStatus = 0

x.Result is always correct

Obviously, if I take out the comments, it works. But as you can imagine, it's slow as hell and not what I can use.

Would be really glad if someone has an answer.

Comment: This is still an issue. I still didn't figure out a solution.

Comment: Simple `Execute` won't end the connection by itself. Maybe it's the command you run that causes your `SshClient` connection to become invalid?